# Get position offset from sprite's position and rotation

Tags: c++, rotation, position, cocos2d-x

I'm using C++ and Cocos2d-x and I'm trying to make the sprite always aim at the mouse cursor. I managed to get this to work, but I noticed the gun's barrel was not quite looking exactly at the cursor, rather the center of the player is.

I used this code to make the player follow the cursor:

```
Vec2 playerPos = getPosition();
this->setRotation(-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES((playerPos - targetPos).getAngle()) - 180);
```

Next I tried adding an offset to the `playerPos` to attempt to locate the gun's nozzle using the following code:

```
Vec2 gunNozzlePos = getPosition() + Vec2(58, -10); // Added offset
this->setRotation(-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES((gunNozzlePos - targetPos).getAngle()) - 180);
```

But the location does not follow the gun's nozzle after the player has been rotated.

Here is a gif showing my issue:

[image: Issue]

How can I take into consideration of the player's rotation to locate the gun's nozzle position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset position should be different for every angle.

For what I understand:

- if angle is 0 offset should be (58, -10)
- if angle is 90 offset should be (10, 58)
- if angle is 180 offset should be (-58, 10)
- if angle is 270 offset should be (-10, -58)

So the offset should be calculated like this:

```
Vec2 gunNozzleOffset = Vec2(58 * cos(yourAngleInRadians) - 10 * sin(yourAngleInRadians), -10 * cos(yourAngleInRadians) + 58 * sin(yourAngleInRadians))
Vec2 gunNozzlePos = getPosition() + gunNozzleOffset;
```

Tell me if it works.

**EDIT** (Did a mistake with a sign)

```
Vec2 gunNozzleOffset = Vec2(58 * cos(yourAngleInRadians) + 10 * sin(yourAngleInRadians), -10 * cos(yourAngleInRadians) + 58 * sin(yourAngleInRadians))
Vec2 gunNozzlePos = getPosition() + gunNozzleOffset;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this code and made the rotation at the center of the player but drew the `gunNozzlePos` from the code in your answer and it came out with this weird result https://i.gyazo.com/4537125ff68cd6ee7ed106893b4dc46c.gif

Comment: Okay I've done it correctly but the dot doesn't quite follow the tip, but it's very close.
https://i.gyazo.com/0ff76e0da961dd8158b1ac853ed25bd8.gif

Comment: @Acidic check the edit, I actually did a mistake with a sign.